When adjusting for covariates in GWAS, do the covariates need to be unpenalized?
I'm wondering if anyone has come across this problem and advise on how best to proceed:
I'm looking for associations between SNPs and type 2 diabetes (binary trait of 0 or 1) using genotyped data (this is data that is 0, 1, or 2). The effect sizes need to be adjusted for covariates which in this instance are the first 10 principal components (floats), sex, and age.
I'm using sci-kit learn libraries, gridSearchCV with LogisticRegression. Some of the literature report doing this analysis using unpenalized covariates when using penalized regression. This is to ensure the covariates are kept during the training as the covariates may have an effect on the genetic data and final effect sizes need to be adjusted for that (i.e. confounding). However, sci-kit learn doesn't natively support this as far as I can tell.
I have two questions:

Is there a way to customize the penalties per feature in a sci-kit learn library? Or is there possibly another solution I can consider?

I have trained several models with the covariates with only 1 of the covariates in a couple of the models having a beta coefficient of 0. Does this mean the model kept the covariates and those results are valid?


Alternatively, I may need to rewrite everything in R to use the glm library which natively supports this but wanted to reach out before going that route.
Any advise is appreciated.

You certainly don’t want to use a lasso (L1) penalty for covariates, as parsimony is not needed.  Use L2 (ridge) penalty if you need any penalty.  How do you know the PCA captured the important aspects of the covariates?  How do you know that age is linear?

@FrankHarrell - Thanks for the response and questions. PCs are commonly used to adjust for population stratification in which some of the genetic features are attributed to the population lineage instead of the disease. Standard practice in GWAS includes covariates: age, PCA's, and sex. Another option is to replace the binary outcome with the residuals from and unpenalized model trained on the covariates and use linear regression instead of logistic regression. However, this complicates the interpretation of the betas as they won't be reported as OR but may be OK for my purposes.

I don’t like multi-stage methods using residuals.  Some models don’t even have residuals.  And it would be good to demonstrate the adequaceyof $PC_{1}, \ldots, PC_{10}$ in capturing what’s needed, i.e., get a chunk test for $PC_{11}, \ldots, PC_{20}$.

@FrankHarrell-Thanks for your help on this. I ended up converting my code to an R script and used the glm library which is straightforward and easy to set covariates with a zero penalty. Adding that extra stage was more complicated.
